# Why does Gradle fail with "Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size" in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I created a Gradle wrapper with

```
$ gradle wrapper --gradle-version 5.0 --distribution-type all
```

...and now have

```
$ ./gradlew -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-11-26 11:48:43 UTC
Revision:     7fc6e5abf2fc5fe0824aec8a0f5462664dbcd987

Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4
Kotlin:       1.3.10
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.3 x86_64
```

I then committed the wrapper files in my Git repo's root dir, with the correct `rwx` permissions.

I have the following in my `gradle.properties` file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1048m
```

Now I wrote a simple Jenkins pipeline that does nothing but

```
node('build-node') {
  stage('Clone') {
      // clones the repo
  }
  stage('Build') {
    sh "./gradlew -version"
  }
}
```

When I run the pipeline, I get

```
+ ./gradlew -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
```

But when I ssh to the build node as the same user (ubuntu) as the Jenkins pipeline executes as, and run the same `./gradlew -version` command, I don't get the error.

Why is it failing in a Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System, need to set this

```
GRADLE_OPTS
-Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```